# Google Map is not loading in ionic

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

Html Code:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="MapController">
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true">
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Controller.js

```
.controller('MapController', function($scope){
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

    var mylatlon = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1923716,72.8574557);
    var mapOptions= {
        center: mylatlon,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeID.ROADMAP            
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    $scope.map = map;

});
})
```

style.css

```
.scroll{
    height: 100%;
}

#map{
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Output:

[Google map is not displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebjNI.png)

Questions:

I have uploaded all the work that i have done , now my issue is google maps is not displayed after running the ionic app. It shows the white screen as shown in the image. Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
        var mylatlon = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1923716,72.8574557);
        var mapOptions= {
            center: mylatlon,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeID.ROADMAP            
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

});
```

and delete this

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){

var mylatlon = new google.maps.LatLng(19.1923716,72.8574557);
var mapOptions= {
    center: mylatlon,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeID.ROADMAP            
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
$scope.map = map;
});
```

So when you enter at the view, google loads the map to your div#map. I haven't used google maps but I guess it's going to work.